# Unable to clear formatting in Notes app

Tags: macos, notes.app, formatting

I'm trying to get into using the Notes app for just keeping track of my thoughts while I'm working. As I'm typing away I might decide to make some text in *italics* and then later revert back to normal text. You know, absolutely barebones basic rich text editing.

The trouble is that when I try to turn off italics (or bold, underline, or whatever) and continue typing the text still shows up in italics. The Format->Font menu shows that the formatting has been turned off and yet when I type more text it still shows up with formatting.

Has anyone had this problem? Any ideas on how to make the damned app work properly?

edit: Italics seems to be the main culprit here, I can usually turn of other formatting styles, but once I've triggered italics it won't go back to normal text unless a open a different note and then come back to the one I was editing.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this too. I work around it by always pressing enter a few times before starting any new note. Then I go back to the start. When the formatting gets stuck I can just move down to a blank line and there will be no formatting.